# How to pick elements by array from array of object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I have an array of object, and I want to remove some elements like this.

```
var data = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:11, b:22, c:33, d:44}]
var saveByKeys = ['a', 'c']
```

The result I want is:

```
var reuslt = [{a:1, c:3}, {a:11, c:33}]
```

How to use lodash to do that? One-line would be better

Comment: Which lodash methods did you try? The documents give examples for each method including ones that do what you are asking

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#pick) with `Array.map()` (or lodash's `_.map()`):

```js
const data = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:11, b:22, c:33, d:44}]
const saveByKeys = ['a', 'c']

const result = data.map(o => _.pick(o, saveByKeys))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `lodash` this is how this would look like with ES6:

```js
var data = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:11, b:22, c:33, d:44}]
var keys = ['a', 'c']

const pick = (obj, keys) => keys.reduce((r,c) => (r[c] = obj[c], r),{})
console.log(data.map(x => pick(x, keys)))
```